# Weblogic server not coming to RUNNING state

Tags: weblogic-10.x

When I start my Weblogic server using startWeblogic.cmd, it exits after printing the below messages on the command prompt without any error messages. How to deduce what's wrong and rectify.

```
<Dec 2, 2014 1:05:29 PM IST> <Info> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000377> <Starting WebL
ogic Server with Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM Version 10.0-b19 from Sun Microsyste
ms Inc.>
<Dec 2, 2014 1:05:29 PM IST> <Info> <Management> <BEA-141107> <Version: WebLogic
 Server 10.3  Fri Jul 25 16:30:05 EDT 2008 1137967 >
<Dec 2, 2014 1:05:31 PM IST> <Warning> <Management> <BEA-141230> <Could Not loca
te descriptor file for System Resource : WseeJmsModule.>
<Dec 2, 2014 1:05:31 PM IST> <Warning> <Management> <BEA-141230> <Could Not loca
te descriptor file for System Resource : cgDataSource.>
<Dec 2, 2014 1:05:31 PM IST> <Warning> <Management> <BEA-141230> <Could Not loca
te descriptor file for System Resource : cgDataSource-nonXA.>
<Dec 2, 2014 1:05:32 PM IST> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server stat
e changed to STARTING>
<Dec 2, 2014 1:05:32 PM IST> <Info> <WorkManager> <BEA-002900> <Initializing sel
f-tuning thread pool>

C:\bea\user_projects\domains\DomainName\bin>cd
```

Further I see the following in the log file of the server I tried starting

```
####<Dec 2, 2014 1:05:35 PM IST> <Critical> <WebLogicServer> <BE-SYS-617> <AdminServer> <main> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1417505735150> <BEA-000386> <Server subsystem failed. Reason: java.lang.AssertionError: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
java.lang.AssertionError: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at weblogic.descriptor.DescriptorManager$SecurityServiceImpl$SecurityProxy._invokeServiceMethod(DescriptorManager.java:175)
    at weblogic.descriptor.DescriptorManager$SecurityServiceImpl$SecurityProxy.decrypt(DescriptorManager.java:192)
    at weblogic.descriptor.DescriptorManager$SecurityServiceImpl.decrypt(DescriptorManager.java:114)
    at weblogic.descriptor.internal.AbstractDescriptorBean._decrypt(AbstractDescriptorBean.java:990)
    at weblogic.management.configuration.SecurityConfigurationMBeanImpl.getCredential(SecurityConfigurationMBeanImpl.java:704)
    at weblogic.security.internal.ServerPrincipalValidatorImpl.getSecret(ServerPrincipalValidatorImpl.java:88)
    at weblogic.security.internal.ServerPrincipalValidatorImpl.sign(ServerPrincipalValidatorImpl.java:67)
    at weblogic.security.service.PrivilegedActions$SignPrincipalAction.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityServiceManager.createServerID(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityServiceManager.getServerID(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityServiceManager.sendASToWire(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.server.channels.ChannelService.resetQOS(ChannelService.java:273)
    at weblogic.server.channels.ChannelService.start(ChannelService.java:244)
    at weblogic.t3.srvr.SubsystemRequest.run(SubsystemRequest.java:64)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:201)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:173)
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at weblogic.descriptor.DescriptorManager$SecurityServiceImpl$SecurityProxy._invokeServiceMethod(DescriptorManager.java:173)
    at weblogic.descriptor.DescriptorManager$SecurityServiceImpl$SecurityProxy.decrypt(DescriptorManager.java:192)
    at weblogic.descriptor.DescriptorManager$SecurityServiceImpl.decrypt(DescriptorManager.java:114)
    at weblogic.descriptor.internal.AbstractDescriptorBean._decrypt(AbstractDescriptorBean.java:990)
    at weblogic.management.configuration.SecurityConfigurationMBeanImpl.getCredential(SecurityConfigurationMBeanImpl.java:704)
    at weblogic.security.internal.ServerPrincipalValidatorImpl.getSecret(ServerPrincipalValidatorImpl.java:88)
    at weblogic.security.internal.ServerPrincipalValidatorImpl.sign(ServerPrincipalValidatorImpl.java:67)
    at weblogic.security.service.PrivilegedActions$SignPrincipalAction.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityServiceManager.createServerID(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityServiceManager.getServerID(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityServiceManager.sendASToWire(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.server.channels.ChannelService.resetQOS(ChannelService.java:273)
    at weblogic.server.channels.ChannelService.start(ChannelService.java:244)
    at weblogic.t3.srvr.SubsystemRequest.run(SubsystemRequest.java:64)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:201)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:173)
weblogic.security.internal.encryption.EncryptionServiceException: com.rsa.jsafe.JSAFE_PaddingException: Could not perform unpadding: invalid pad byte.
    at weblogic.security.internal.encryption.JSafeEncryptionServiceImpl.decryptBytes(JSafeEncryptionServiceImpl.java:78)
    at weblogic.security.internal.encryption.JSafeEncryptionServiceImpl.decryptString(JSafeEncryptionServiceImpl.java:94)
    at weblogic.security.internal.encryption.ClearOrEncryptedService.decrypt(ClearOrEncryptedService.java:87)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at weblogic.descriptor.DescriptorManager$SecurityServiceImpl$SecurityProxy._invokeServiceMethod(DescriptorManager.java:173)
    at weblogic.descriptor.DescriptorManager$SecurityServiceImpl$SecurityProxy.decrypt(DescriptorManager.java:192)
    at weblogic.descriptor.DescriptorManager$SecurityServiceImpl.decrypt(DescriptorManager.java:114)
    at weblogic.descriptor.internal.AbstractDescriptorBean._decrypt(AbstractDescriptorBean.java:990)
    at weblogic.management.configuration.SecurityConfigurationMBeanImpl.getCredential(SecurityConfigurationMBeanImpl.java:704)
    at weblogic.security.internal.ServerPrincipalValidatorImpl.getSecret(ServerPrincipalValidatorImpl.java:88)
    at weblogic.security.internal.ServerPrincipalValidatorImpl.sign(ServerPrincipalValidatorImpl.java:67)
    at weblogic.security.service.PrivilegedActions$SignPrincipalAction.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityServiceManager.createServerID(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityServiceManager.getServerID(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityServiceManager.sendASToWire(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.server.channels.ChannelService.resetQOS(ChannelService.java:273)
    at weblogic.server.channels.ChannelService.start(ChannelService.java:244)
    at weblogic.t3.srvr.SubsystemRequest.run(SubsystemRequest.java:64)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:201)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:173)
com.rsa.jsafe.JSAFE_PaddingException: Could not perform unpadding: invalid pad byte.
    at com.rsa.jsafe.JA_PKCS5Padding.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.rsa.jsafe.JG_BlockCipher.decryptFinal(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.security.internal.encryption.JSafeEncryptionServiceImpl.decryptBytes(JSafeEncryptionServiceImpl.java:68)
    at weblogic.security.internal.encryption.JSafeEncryptionServiceImpl.decryptString(JSafeEncryptionServiceImpl.java:94)
    at weblogic.security.internal.encryption.ClearOrEncryptedService.decrypt(ClearOrEncryptedService.java:87)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at weblogic.descriptor.DescriptorManager$SecurityServiceImpl$SecurityProxy._invokeServiceMethod(DescriptorManager.java:173)
    at weblogic.descriptor.DescriptorManager$SecurityServiceImpl$SecurityProxy.decrypt(DescriptorManager.java:192)
    at weblogic.descriptor.DescriptorManager$SecurityServiceImpl.decrypt(DescriptorManager.java:114)
    at weblogic.descriptor.internal.AbstractDescriptorBean._decrypt(AbstractDescriptorBean.java:990)
    at weblogic.management.configuration.SecurityConfigurationMBeanImpl.getCredential(SecurityConfigurationMBeanImpl.java:704)
    at weblogic.security.internal.ServerPrincipalValidatorImpl.getSecret(ServerPrincipalValidatorImpl.java:88)
    at weblogic.security.internal.ServerPrincipalValidatorImpl.sign(ServerPrincipalValidatorImpl.java:67)
    at weblogic.security.service.PrivilegedActions$SignPrincipalAction.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityServiceManager.createServerID(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityServiceManager.getServerID(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityServiceManager.sendASToWire(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.server.channels.ChannelService.resetQOS(ChannelService.java:273)
    at weblogic.server.channels.ChannelService.start(ChannelService.java:244)
    at weblogic.t3.srvr.SubsystemRequest.run(SubsystemRequest.java:64)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:201)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:173)
> 
####<Dec 2, 2014 1:05:35 PM IST> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BE-SYS-617> <AdminServer> <main> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1417505735259> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to FAILED> 
####<Dec 2, 2014 1:05:35 PM IST> <Error> <WebLogicServer> <BE-SYS-617> <AdminServer> <main> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1417505735259> <BEA-000383> <A critical service failed. The server will shut itself down> 
####<Dec 2, 2014 1:05:35 PM IST> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BE-SYS-617> <AdminServer> <main> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1417505735259> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to FORCE_SHUTTING_DOWN> 
####<Dec 2, 2014 1:05:35 PM IST> <Info> <WebLogicServer> <BE-SYS-617> <AdminServer> <main> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1417505735259> <BEA-000236> <Stopping execute threads.>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general this is one of two problems:

- Are you running in production or development mode? If in development mode, it's possible you have an encrypted password in a config file that you don't want. You can put in a clear text password to get around the problem.

  - You can turn switch to development mode by setting `production-mode-enabled` to false in domain_home/config/config.xml
  - Check config/config.xml and any JDBC under config/jdbc/ for encrypted AES passwords and set them to clear text
  - Use these as a reference if you need it [Weblogic Deployment Exception : PaddingException: Could not perform unpadding: invalid pad byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12911771/weblogic-deployment-exception-paddingexception-could-not-perform-unpadding-i) ----or this----- [padding exception](http://weblogic-wonders.com/weblogic/2010/11/04/com-rsa-jsafe-jsafe_paddingexception-could-not-perform-unpadding-invalid-pad-byte/)
- The other (and more difficult problem) could be that the crypto jar files in your java install do not match what weblogic is expecting.

  - It could be related to the jars in your java jre/lib/ext dir. You may need to add the weblogic /server/lib/cryptojFIPS.jar to your JDK/jre/lib/ext directory if it has a different version.